# Headers not being modified with Response object in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am trying to return a PDF to the browser using Symfony 2, so once I have located the file, I use:

```
return new Response(readfile($file_path), 200, array(
'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'
));
```

but if I load the page, headers are not being modified and the content is not being interpreted as a pdf...

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 31 Mar 2012 20:39:20 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=XXXX; path=/
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
```

I'm lost with this problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`readfile` executes first, and starts sending the file to the client. This triggers the headers to be generated. Then the return value of readfile is passed to `Response`. When Response is returned to the client it's impossible for PHP to change the headers because they were triggered when readfile ran.

Replace `readfile` with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: The problem with `file_get_contents` is that it loads the file in memory so it can't be used to download big files. Is there a way to use `readfile` with symfony2 ?

Comment: I don't see anything built in to handle that. I haven't tried it, but it looks like you could create a subclass of \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response that overrides sendContent() to use readfile. The default implementation expects you to pass the actual content to the class, your subclass might get a filename instead. I see potential trouble with getContent(), it's expected to return the actual content, but that won't be an option without file_get_contents.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to use the following

```
new StreamedResponse(function () use ($file) {
    readfile($file);
}, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/png');
```

Comment: nice one thx, here is the use statement:
`use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;`